# How can I reformat HTML to add line breaks after closing tags?

Tags: html, format, sublimetext2

I've got an html file that is all lumped together...eg:

```
<tr><td class="stat_WS">6</td><td class="stat_BS">6</td><td class="stat_St">3/4</td><td     class="stat_To">3</td><td class="stat_Wo">2</td><td class="stat_In">6</td><td class="stat_At">3/4</td><td class="stat_Ld">9</td><td class="stat_Save">5+/2(i)</td></tr></tbody></table><div class="wargear">Wargear</div><table class="options"><tr class="opt_dePGL"><td class="name">Phantasm Grenade Launcher</td><td class="cost">0</td></tr>
```

I want to automatically run through it and break the line after every closing  tag. Help?

Comment: I've never used [tag:sublimetext2], so I'm unsure of its use; but I *do* routinely use [http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier](http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier) for tidying up, and indenting, posted HTML (for badly-formatted questions on this site, as much as for my own stuff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to do this within Sublime, hit `Ctrl+H` and replace: `(</[a-z]+>)` with `$1\n`. (make sure to check "Regular Expresseion")

For a full reformatting, there are lots of formatters online, like this one: http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html

Comment: Cool, thanks. For whatever reason my google-fu failed me trying to find html formatters. I tried 4 or 5 and none of them formatted the line breaks in. Free Formatter worked though.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I'm assuming ctrl+H is windows command? What would the equivalent OSX command be?

Comment: Probably Cmd+H. Ctrl is usually replaced by Cmd. If it's not Cmd+H, go to Find > Replace.

Comment: Gotcha. Cmd+H is hide. I thought you might be referring to ctrl-H. I'm assuming like what's there by default...when I do option-command-F (find/replace), it doesn't have anything like the reg-ex above, I'll play around though.

Comment: There's no regex button? Are you 100% sure? It should be here: http://puu.sh/1at1v